# How to pass an ArrayList<String> to a bean

Tags: java, jsf-2

I'am using JSF2.0,
I want to pass to a bean a property has the type ArrayList ,can I do that? if ues what will be the property-class!

`private ArrayList<String> selectedEnvironment;`

```
<managed-bean>
 <managed-bean-name>Mybean</managed-bean-name> 
 <managed-bean-class>package.Mybean</managed-bean-class> 
 <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
 <managed-property>
   <property-name>selectedEnvironment</property-name>
   <property-class>?</property-class>
   <value>#{FMTools.selectedEnvironment}</value>
 </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Thank you

Comment: If you are using JSF2 why are you writing managed-beans configuration? Isn't it easier to use annotations? `@ManagedBean`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it if the `<value>` is dynamic already (you're using EL in it). JSF will take care of it. Just omit the `<property-class>`. You only need it if the `<value>` is static and you want to set it as something else than `String` (which it defaults to).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, [since JSF 2.0 you don't need the stinkin' faces-config anymore](http://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/faces_config_xml_we_don) to declare managed beans and managed properties. You can use annotations.

```
@ManagedBean(name="MyBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{FMTools.selectedEnvironment}")
    private List<String> selectedEnvironment;

    // ...
}
```